# Feed my command line to a function or program if it matches a specific pattern

Tags: shell, zsh

My end-game here is to have the following:

```bsh
$ python3 -c "print(\"Hello, world!\")"
Hello, world!
$ >>> print("Hello, world!")
Hello, world!
```

Basically, every time my command line starts with `>>>`, I want the rest of the command line to be fed to `python3` with the `-c` switch.

If it was possible to declare (and use) a `>>>` function, it would be implemented as follow:

```bsh
>>>() {
    python3 -c "$@"
}
```

For the record, I'm using `zsh`.

My first try was to create an alias named `>>>`, but it's not valid on any of the two shells. Next I tried to create a `>>>` function, and even though it's valid on ZSH, there is seemingly no way to call it (be it with `>>>` or `\>\>\>`).

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since that needs to happen before zsh parses the line (as you need it to be python syntax, not zsh syntax), you'd need to do it in the `accept-line` widget:

```
accept-line() {
  emulate -L zsh
  set -o extendedglob
  case $BUFFER in
    ('>>>'*)
      zle -I
      fc -R =(print -r -- $BUFFER)
      python -c "${BUFFER##>>> #}"
      BUFFER=
      ;;
    (*) zle .$WIDGET
  esac
}
zle -N accept-line
```

Comment: Wow, that's great. I didn't know about `accept-line`. This works like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This works for `zsh`, remember to escape special characters/quote when defining the function:

```
'>>>'() {
    python3 -c "$@"
}
```

```
'bad|idea<for>a command name'() { :; }
```

Comment: The issue is that now I need to call it with `$ \>\>\>` which is not desirable